# Flutter couldn't run

Tags: git, flutter

I have download flutter and git and also added them in PATH but when I try to 
run it in command Prompt, It shows an Error.

Error is

> 'where' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable
>   program or batch file. Error: Unable to find git in your PATH.

I have installed it in c://flutter and set path of c://flutter/bin

But it will run when I lunch command prompt as administrator. Plz help me to solve my problem.

Thanks,

Comment: You need to share more info, or we can't help you. Where are they installed? Add that info and your complete path.

Answer (score 2):

Ensure `C:\Windows\System32\` is added to your `PATH` variable.

[Adding directory to PATH Environment Variable in Windows](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9546324/adding-directory-to-path-environment-variable-in-windows)

Answer (score 0):

I think the error you're getting is because **git** is not installed in your device.

Nevertheless, You can try running Flutter after installing the followings:

- Android Studio
- Chrome (A browser)
- Git